# Error getting list of objects from db in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server 2014 and I was trying to generate data script from a database but I kept getting this error:

> Error getting list of objects from db_name

The query for creating tables and inserting data was successful and generating schema script was successful too. I did some research and found this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c000bed-e203-4a80-8500-432c158404bc/generate-scripts-error-getting-the-list-of-objects?forum=sqltools).

I did turn auto close option off according to a guy's reply but it didn't work, I followed up on the link to another thread but there's nothing.

Comment: can you tell what are the steps you are followed?

Comment: simple, basic steps: first I create database named infoDB, then 3 tables plus setting up primary keys and foreign keys. Then I insert into these table 5 rows of data each

Comment: I can show you the query [here](http://codepad.org/bcLC2w2a) @bmsqldev

Comment: Databasename -> Right Click-> Generate Scripts. Is this the way you generate the scripts?

Comment: yes, then I change the script type in advanced option to "data only" @bmsqldev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this issue and what appeared to solve it for me was to generate a "schema only" script. Once this is successful, go back and try to generate the "data only" script again.

Comment: I tried this and the first error was gone, but then I get `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index (mscorlib)`

Answer (score 9):

1. Click on "Save Report" button
2. Open the generated file and analyze the message regarding the error, this can give a clue on how to solve the problem.

In my case was that the sql output file was being used by another process. I closed the SQSMS, reopened and that's it.

Comment: I had cyclic dependencies - fixed with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26925004/4378740

Comment: Oddly, when I clicked Save Report it decided to try the first step again and then successfully went through all the steps and generated the script (not sure if any report was saved?)